# In android, is there any way to get the name of application which sent SMS for each SMS

Tags: java, android, logging, service, sms

For each SMS I want to log the the **name of the application which sent the SMS**. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112764/how-can-i-log-all-sent-sms-along-with-package-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender information that you get automatically via the Sms APIs is all lower level than the sending app, e.g. originating address or email address.

SMS is not really interested in application information, because that is too high level. I think your only way to get this information would be by some roundabout method that depends on action from the sender.