# How can I log all sent SMS along with package name?

Tags: android, logging, sms, smsmanager

I am trying to develop an app which logs all sent SMS along with UID or package name of the application which triggered that event. I am doing this for a research purpose.Thanks in advance ...
I am looking to log the UID or package name of application which send that sms.

Sorry for my english if it is disgusting.

Comment: use content observer. read [this article](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/sms-mms-contentobserver-and-service-t12938.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking log the UID or package name of application which send that sms

Comment: hm, i think thats impossible to do

Comment: Hmm. Any way thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a series of researches, I found that package name of application which triggered the SMS is explicitly stored in creator field(index 19) of SMS DB.